# No se encontró la extensión mysqli. phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

Hola tengo este problema phpmyadmin se les presenta un error *No se encontró la extensión mysqli.*

Answer (score 3):

Hola comunidad si en algún momento en la instalación de phpmyadmin se les presenta un error *No se encontró la extensión mysqli.* la solución es la siguiente para usuarios ubuntu:
**php --version** revisamos la versión de nuestro php, en este caso yo tengo la 7.3.
**sudo apt-get install php7.3-mysql** instalamos 
**sudo service apache2 restart** y reiniciamos el apache2 y se soluciona el problema.